# Create an IP Address as a hex value

Tags: python, hex

I am running the below function in python (3x) to generate a random IP Address

```
def get_ip_address(self):
            x = ".".join(map(str, (random.randint(0, 255)
                                   for _ in range(4))))
            return x
```

However I need to convert the IP address generated into a hex value, I dont need to do anything complicated and am happy to either convert x post creation or do it in the create Ip address function. I need to be able to easily see what the IP address is I am creating and converting as this is part of a test Suite and at the other end the Hex IP Address is converted back. I also need it in the format 0xb15150ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're complicating things. Just take the IP address as an int and convert it into hex:

```
# Generate a random 
>>> hex(random.randint(0,(1<<32)-1))
'0x85c90851'
>>> hex(random.randint(0,(1<<32)-1))
'0xfb4f592d'
```

If you always wish for it to be exactly 8 hex digits, and strip the `0x` up front, you may as well format it straight like this:

```
>>> "{:0X}".format(random.randint(0,(1<<32)-1))
'4CC27A5E'
```

---

If you wish to know the IP, use the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module like so:

```
import ipaddress
>>> ip = random.randint(0,(1<<32)-1)
>>> ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
IPv4Address('238.53.246.162')
>>> "{:0X}".format(ip)
'EE35F6A2'
```

Comment: Thanks this works great for encoding, but I need to know what the IP address is before its encoded (should have mentioned that in the question sorry).

Comment: @RichardC Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend you function as follows:

```
def get_ip_address():

    x = ".".join(map(str, (random.randint(0, 255)
                           for _ in range(4))))

    # Split you created decimal IP in single numbers
    ip_split_dec = str(x).split('.')

    # Convert to hex
    ip_split_hex = [int(t) for t in ip_split_dec]

    # Construct hex IP adress
    # ip_hex = '.'.join([hex(X)[2:] for X in ip_split_hex]) # Format hh.hh.hh.hh
    ip_hex = '0x' + ''.join([hex(X)[2:] for X in ip_split_hex]) # Format 0xhhhhhhhh

    return ip_hex
```

which will give you

```
>>> address = get_ip_address()
>>> 0xa535f08b
```

You can also combine this with the construction of your decimal IP to spare some code lines

Btw: As long as your function is no method of a class, theres is no need for the `self` in your function definition

Comment: The function is part of a larger class hence the self. I need the IP address to be in the format 0xb15150ca thanks.

Comment: In that case you can use the edited code from my answer or adapt the code of @bharel answer below

Comment: Going for the other option, this works but the other option is a simpler overall solution.